# opening images with Python PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am using a sample NEF and expecting a 4288×2848 image, but get 160x120 with the code below.  Is this as expected in that PIL doesn't support NEF?

```
from PIL import Image
image="./blah.nef"
im=Image.open(image)
im.size
```

Answer (score 3):

You're getting the JPEG thumbnail embedded in the NEF. It's pretty cool that it got far enough into the file to find the thumbnail.

Answer (score 2):

Did you check the [Python Image Library's documentation](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/index.htm)? I don't see the Nikon RAW format (NEF) in the list of supported image formats. You'll need to find a library or application that explicitly supports this format, such as [UFRaw](http://ufraw.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

I know the question's old, but you can use `rawpy` nowadays:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import rawpy
import imageio

with rawpy.imread('blah.nef') as raw:
    rgb = raw.postprocess(gamma=(1,1), no_auto_bright=True, output_bps=16)

# Extract individual bands for fun
R = rgb[:,:,0]
G = rgb[:,:,1]
B = rgb[:,:,2]
```